# Type of string escape done defaultly by cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

Does cakePHP use mysql_real_escape_string for sql data and strip_tags and html encode by default or should it be done by the user/programmer?

Comment: I'll give you 29% of my answer until you start following the rules of the site.

Comment: I am sorry! I did not understand what you said.

Comment: I am not sure of how to upvote. This is the first time somebody spoke about upvoting. How do you do that. I always appreciate people once we solve the problem. I would love to upvote, but have no idea how it is done.

Comment: the huge up arrows next to answers

Comment: Thank you for letting me know regarding this!! I'll make sure I follow this from now on. I hope we can get back to the question now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cake's DboMysql adaptor is `mysql_real_escaping` strings, but may do other things for other types and values (such as using `NULL`). See for yourself: http://api.cakephp.org/view_source/dbo-mysql/#l-628